# Why isn't there method that assign value to a variable in programming language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why there is't method that assign value to a variable

I sometimes want to assign value to variable dynamically.

For example, when I wrote like these,

```
taro = Student.new "taro"
ziro = Student.new "ziro"
tarao = Student.new "tarao"
```

I really want to write like these.

```
["taro", "ziro", "tarao"].each do |name|
 varname = Student.new name  
end
```

Why is't there a method like this?

```
asign(varname, value, scope)
```

And Why I can't code like this?

```
["taro", "ziro", "tarao"].each do |name|
  asign(name, Student.new name, GLOBAL)
end
```

This is not a question about how to assign dynamically, but 
a question 'why' isn't there any schema to solve this problem.

I want to know the reason. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I'd suspect it doesn't exist because no one but you thinks it's a good idea or sees a need for it.

Comment: Because "variable variables" are generally a really bad idea, especially in a language like Ruby where you can just use a hash.

Comment: Whoever makes the class could implement behavior like this. If it's an array, split it into it's individual indices.

Comment: Thanks. I understood. It's simply becase useless. Not for technical reason.

Comment: @programmerk I would like to point out that sometimes just because you can, doesn't mean you should

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are actually asking. Are you asking why no language does this? If that is your question, then your premise is wrong: there are plenty of languages in which local variables are just instance variables of a lexical scope object (e.g. Self) or where local variables are just getters and setters on a lexical scope object (e.g. Newspeak) or local variable accesses translate into subroutine calls, or there *are no local variables at all*. For example, in Ioke `a = b` is just syntactic sugar for `=(a, b)`, i.e. calling the method `=`, passing the unevaluated message chain

Comment: `a, b` as an argument. Or are you asking why Ruby isn't one of those languages? In that case, you'll have to ask the designers of Ruby, we can't tell you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing code, but *especially* when using a dynamic language like Ruby, think in terms of *data structures* and not in terms of variables.

What you're looking for is actually this:

```
students = [ "taro", "ziro", "tarao" ].map do |name|
  Student.new(name)
end
```

Where that creates an array of students. These can be referenced as `students[0]` and so on.

If you wanted them indexed by name:

```
students = [ "taro", "ziro", "tarao" ].map do |name|
  [ name, Student.new(name) ]
end.to_h
```

Where then you can call `students['taro']` and get that student. You'll often find that the Ruby solution that's the most minimal is often the most Ruby-like.

Using regular data structures like this helps when you're passing this data from one location in your code to another. Consider how easy this is:

```
best_student(students)
```

Versus this approach:

```
best_student(taro, ziro, tarao, ...)
```

Where each time you add a new student you need to go and change *all* of your code. That's counter-productive.

The version that does roughly what you want is really ugly by comparison, and intentionally so as you're not supposed to do this casually, it shouldn't be easy:

```
[ "taro", "ziro", "tarao" ].map do |name|
  instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", Student.new(name))
end
```

Where that creates instance variables like `@taro` but is also a giant mess compared to the simple version.

Comment: Thank you for your answering.
I understood that what I intended to do can be done by another way.
And I understood what variable is for, what instance variable is for,  and what hash is for.Thanks.